# What is a Python equivalent of Perlbrew?

Tags: python

Is there a Python equivalent of [Perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/)?

Ideally, this `equivalent' would have at least the following two features:

1. Allow for multiple Python isolated installs, ie perlbrew install, list, use...
2. Allow for the installation of `non-core' Python modules to specific Python installs, as in the combination of perlbrew and say [cpanminus](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus)

Thanks ☺

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I d say virtualenv

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/

It seems like the same thing and you use pip to install your packages in your virtual python environments.

Comment: +1 - don't forget virtualenvwrapper to make it even *easier* to manage your virtual environments: http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Answer (score 3):

Pythonbrew - 
Inspired by perlbrew. Similar functionality

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew/